# Adding a new Customer Contact in Quickbooks via QBXML, is it possible?

Tags: php, quickbooks, qbxml

I'm working on integrating a website with Quickbooks via the php framework and the QBWC.

My question has to deal with Customers. I've noticed that the only way to add Contacts to a customer is on customer creation. ContactsMod can only edit existing customer contacts, it requires a ListID and an EditSequence. As such, there also seems to be no way to delete customer contacts once they are created.

Is this a feature that's not completely implemented in QBXML, or can I treat it like an Invoice LineRet item and feed it a ListID of -1 to create a new contact?

To give you an example of where in the structure I'm working, here's the QBXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <CustomerModRq>
            <CustomerMod>
                <ListID >IDTYPE</ListID>
                <EditSequence >STRTYPE</EditSequence>
                etc
                ...
                ...
                <ContactsMod>
                    <ListID >IDTYPE</ListID>
                    <EditSequence >STRTYPE</EditSequence>
                    <FirstName >STRTYPE</FirstName>
                    <MiddleName >STRTYPE</MiddleName>
                    <LastName >STRTYPE</LastName>
                    <JobTitle >STRTYPE</JobTitle>
                </ContactsMod>
            </CustomerMod>
        </CustomerModRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up submitting a ticket to Intuit, and received a response. Customer Contacts is in the schema for QBXML, but is not actually implemented in Quickbooks yet. So quickbooks will not return Contacts data as part of an Add/Mod/Query response, nor will it handle ContactsAdd or ContactsMod statements properly.

It will be implemented in the future, but until it is, that's that!

> "Access to contact information is in the schema, but it has not been implemented in QB.
> We have a request in to get this implemented, but I do not know when it will be completed.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> William Lorfing
>
> Intuit"